# How to set date period condition properly?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
data = [['2019-01-11 16:27:39', 'AC', '2019-01-11 16:54:53'], ['2019-01-11 16:27:39', 'DC', '2019-01-11 16:54:53'], ['2019-01-11 17:03:42', 'AC', '2019-01-14 10:00:25'], ['2019-01-11 17:03:42', 'DC', '2019-01-14 09:58:39'], ['2019-01-11 17:03:42', 'Battery', '2019-01-14 10:00:48'], ['2019-01-11 17:03:48', 'Cell', '2019-01-12 17:26:48'], ['2019-01-14 10:00:36', 'DC', '2019-01-14 10:33:42'], ['2019-01-14 10:32:42', 'AC', '2019-01-14 10:45:27']]    

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Start', 'Alarm', 'End'])  
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

The sense is that DC, Battery and Cell alarms occurr while the AC lasts. So I want to match these alarms with the AC start time by adding the additional column where the start time of the correspondent AC alarm will be put.

The condition sounds like this:  IF AC Start time <= Other Alarms Start time AND AC End time >= Other Alarms End time ==> match the AC Start time with correspondent alarm record.

So I tried to recreate this rule in code:

```
cond =  df.Alarm.ne('AC') & df[df['Alarm']=='AC']['Start'].le(df[df['Alarm']!='AC']['Start']) & df[df['Alarm']=='AC']['End'].ge(df[df['Alarm']!='AC']['End'])
```

But when I apply this condition with np.where to check I get wrong result:

[image]

Any clues how to tune condition are appreciated.

Comment: Sorry if the question is dumb, but am I right to assume that, in theory, there should be no DC/Battery/Cell alarm possible outside of an active AC? It sounds like that is the case from your wording.

Comment: @IvanPopov you are right. In theory, these alarms have sense only within AC duration. But in practice, they can occur without AC, which is somewhat wrong and thus is beyond interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your use of .ge/.le is wrong, as they are pairwise comparisons that happen based on the index, and you pass filtered rows to them, so the indices are different. What I'd do is apply a helper func on the respective slice of the df, i.e. the non-AC entries. The helper uses a separate view into the df (with only the AC entries) for the check it makes, and this way it checks against all AC entries.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['2019-01-11 16:27:39', 'AC', '2019-01-11 16:54:53'],
        ['2019-01-11 16:27:39', 'DC', '2019-01-11 16:54:53'],
        ['2019-01-11 17:03:42', 'AC', '2019-01-14 10:00:25'],
        ['2019-01-11 17:03:42', 'DC', '2019-01-14 09:58:39'],
        ['2019-01-11 17:03:42', 'Battery', '2019-01-14 10:00:48'],
        ['2019-01-11 17:03:48', 'Cell', '2019-01-12 17:26:48'],
        ['2019-01-14 10:00:36', 'DC', '2019-01-14 10:33:42'],
        ['2019-01-14 10:32:42', 'AC', '2019-01-14 10:45:27']]    

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Start', 'Alarm', 'End'])
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

def comparison(entry):
    start = acs['Start'].le(entry['Start'])
    end = acs['End'].ge(entry['End'])
    return (start & end).any()

acs = df[df['Alarm']=='AC']
df['AC start'] = False
df.loc[df['Alarm'] != 'AC', 'AC start'] = df.apply(comparison, axis=1)

print(df)

"""
Out:
                Start    Alarm                 End  AC start
0 2019-01-11 16:27:39       AC 2019-01-11 16:54:53     False
1 2019-01-11 16:27:39       DC 2019-01-11 16:54:53      True
2 2019-01-11 17:03:42       AC 2019-01-14 10:00:25     False
3 2019-01-11 17:03:42       DC 2019-01-14 09:58:39      True
4 2019-01-11 17:03:42  Battery 2019-01-14 10:00:48     False
5 2019-01-11 17:03:48     Cell 2019-01-12 17:26:48      True
6 2019-01-14 10:00:36       DC 2019-01-14 10:33:42     False
7 2019-01-14 10:32:42       AC 2019-01-14 10:45:27     False
"""
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. I tried also columnname.values approach (I thought that should help me to avoid comparsion by index), but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of solution other than involving kind of cartesian product (but it works):

```
# create valid_alarms base
valid_alarms = df.copy()
valid_alarms['constant'] = 1
valid_alarms = valid_alarms.merge(valid_alarms, how='left', on=['constant'])
valid_alarms = \
valid_alarms[
    (valid_alarms['Alarm_x']=='AC') &
    (valid_alarms['Alarm_y']!='AC')
]
valid_alarms = \
valid_alarms[
    (valid_alarms['Start_x']<=valid_alarms['Start_y']) &
    (valid_alarms['End_y']<=valid_alarms['End_x'])
]

# merging valid_alarms to df
df = \
df.merge(
    valid_alarms[['id_y','constant']],
    how='left',
    left_on=['id'],
    right_on=['id_y']
).drop(
    columns=['id','id_y']
).rename(
    columns={'constant':'valid_alarm'}
).fillna(
    {
        'valid_alarm':0
    }
)

df['valid_alarm'] = df['valid_alarm']*1
df

                Start    Alarm                 End  valid_alarm
0 2019-01-11 16:27:39       AC 2019-01-11 16:54:53          0.0
1 2019-01-11 16:27:39       DC 2019-01-11 16:54:53          1.0
2 2019-01-11 17:03:42       AC 2019-01-14 10:00:25          0.0
3 2019-01-11 17:03:42       DC 2019-01-14 09:58:39          1.0
4 2019-01-11 17:03:42  Battery 2019-01-14 10:00:48          0.0
5 2019-01-11 17:03:48     Cell 2019-01-12 17:26:48          1.0
6 2019-01-14 10:00:36       DC 2019-01-14 10:33:42          0.0
7 2019-01-14 10:32:42       AC 2019-01-14 10:45:27          0.0
```